# Data Table row selection(single) in Primefaces 3.5 selects all rows

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to add and remove rows in DataTable and using buttons to add and remove the rows respectively by single selection.

My html/jsf code is :

```
<p:dataTable id="creditTable" rowIndexVar="sn" 
                                value="#{cpeTrainingMB.cpeTrainingObj.cpeTrainigSchDetail}"
                                var="cpeDetail" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100" 
                                selectionMode="single" 
                                rowKey="#{cpeDetail.id}">

                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":cpe:creditTable" listener="#{cpeTrainingMB.onRowSelect}"/>

                                    <p:column headerText="Sn">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{sn+1}"></h:outputText>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Date">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{cpeDetail.fromDtBS}"></h:outputText> 
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Credit HR">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{cpeDetail.creditHr}"></h:outputText>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
```

The problem is that when I add more than one data, and then select a row to delete , it selects all the rows at once which is not required.
It works well for only one row.

The backing methods/functions are listed below :

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event){

        cpeScheSelected = null;
        this.cpeScheSelected = (CPETrainingScheduleModel)event.getObject();

        cpeTrainingScheObj = null;

        cpeTrainingScheObj = this.cpeScheSelected;

    }
```

Comment: Hello, is there someone

Comment: Are you sure that all object added to your dataTable have a not null id?

Comment: Sorry, I had the all the id null. But my id will be auto generated while saving to database. And so, I have generated id for selection purpose. I want to know that is it possible to have a rowkey other than the fields of the object ? Like the auto generated serial number for the display.

Comment: I'd say that it has to be a field of the object - at least I've never heard otherwise. You can always implement SelectableDataModel instead of specifying rowKey - but that's a bit more coding. I take it that generating the ids has solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, by generating ids it solved.

Answer (score 0):

All elements listed in the dataTable must have a not-null value in the rowKey property (in this case - id field). Nulls will lead to the behaviour described in the question. An alternative to specifying rowKey is implementing SelectableDataModel with custom method `public Object getRowKey(RowClass rc)`.